# The body I am send through as a POST request gives me a bad request, where am I going wrong using HTTP.NET

Tags: c#, api, http, automation

The body I am send through as a POST request gives me a bad request, where am I going wrong using HTTP.NET.

Here is my code, I've tried deserializing the json body and I have also tried reading it from a file but still get bad request, am I missing something

```
            string accessKeyId = "<KEY>";
            string secretAccessKey = "<KEY>";
            var clientSecurity = new ClientSecurity(new SignatureVersionFactory());
            var url = GetCreateSchedulingJobUrl(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt");

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            //httpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //httpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new 
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            using var client = new HttpClient();
             
            var body = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt");
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(content);
            httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
            MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            clientSecurity.SignRequestAsync(httpRequestMessage, accessKeyId, 
            secretAccessKey, SigningAlgorithms.S3S);
            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
            string statusMsg = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I have also tried:

```
                var body = @"{
                                " + "\n" +
                             @"    ""name"": ""Some name""
                             " + "\n" +
                             @"}";
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                request.Content = new StringContent(content);
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
                MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                response = httpClient.PostAsync(webUrl,request.Content).Result;
```

BUT still get bad request, are there alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this and try again

```
var content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt");
// var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
```

If it works tidy up afterwards.

`JsonSerialize()` serializes objects to JSON strings.  You are reading in a JSON string (an already serialized representation of an object) and then serializing it again.  Have a look at this...

```
public class Obj
{
  public string name;
}
:
  var obj = new Obj { name = "value" };
  var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
  var json2 = "{ \"name\":\"value\" }";
  var json3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json1);
  Console.WriteLine($"json1:{json1}");
  Console.WriteLine($"json2:{json2}");
  Console.WriteLine($"json3:{json3}");
```

which produces

```
json1:{"name":"value"}
json2:{ "name":"value" }
json3:"{\"name\":\"value\"}"

      <- plain old string ->
```